# Map-widget-like, draggable <div>

Tags: jquery-plugins, javascript

I'd like to embed my custom `HTML` in an area that is draggable, like the `JavaScript` Map widgets.

For example, I want to put a `1000x1000` `<div>` inside a `480x320` `<div>`, without scrollbars (`overflow:hidden`) and be able to adjust the position of the inner layer by dragging it with the mouse. Ideally I'd like to catch scroll events too.

I could implement it myself, but I'm wondering if there's a ready-to-use, well-tested cross-browser piece of `JavaScript` that could do this for me. Ideally a [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be able to use the [Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) plugin, and just make the container smaller than the draggable div.

In the example on that page, if you make the `#demo-frame` smaller than `.demo`, I think it gives the effect you are looking for.

Comment: Yep, it looks like it gives me a similar result. The only things I needed to change are, remove scroll bars, and add a restriction so that I can't drag it "over", so that the background of the outer box would become visible.